# Can I re-run a scaffold to update the update/new form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I ran scaffold and it created the new/update routes and html forms, and then later I added a few columns to the database via a migration, is it possible to update the html form that was generated?

Comment: You can re-run the rails g scaffold command and it will prompt you which files to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can..and you should do it to update your views.And it will ask some overwrite prompts

Comment: it says migration already exists, and doesn't say to override?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can simply run `rails generate scaffold <model> <fields>` and add `--skip` or `--force` on the end.  This will do exactly what it sounds like it will do.  It will either **override** files that all ready exist or **skip** the files that all ready exist.